# How can I connect to multiple servers efficiently with ssh using Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

We run a VSphere at the office, meaning I am using a lot of different ssh connections to systems. 
I really like [Mputty](http://www.ttyplus.com/multi-tabbed-putty/) and [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download.html) on Windows, because they save and remember how I connected to my servers. So connection is always a double click away.

Thing is, I am running Linux most of the time, with a direct command line. 
I would like to find an equivalent of mputty for linux. Some kind of SSH connection manager, that would allow me to connect to my servers based on previous connections.

So far I am using CTRL-R and pick from history, but the interest is limited, as I still have to enter credentials.

What do you guys use? 
**Preferably, I would like not to have to rely on an external software, but get it directly from CL.**

Comment: Please check out our younger sister site: [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Here your question is [off-topic](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: Alternatively, rewrite the question along the line of "How can I connect to multiple servers efficiently with ssh" if something like my approach is viable for you.

Comment: Indeed, @SvW. I do not ask for software, but rather a 'method'. I will rename

Comment: @DeerHunter I do not see this as a software recommendation question because it explicitly prefers a solution with the already installed software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a product recommendation question, making it [off-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

However, I suggest an alternative approach: `~/.ssh/config`. I use it to store all the non-standard parameters for specific hosts and therefore very seldom use anything beyond `ssh host` and even that is abstracted away in a bash alias, ending me with only using `@ host` to connect to a machine.

An example from my file:

```
Host headnode
   Hostname headnode.cluster
   ProxyCommand ssh -a -X username@clustergateway.hoster.net netcat -v %h 22
   User username_on_cluster
   ForwardX11 yes
```

All I have to do to use it is `ssh headnode`.

See `man ssh_config` for more ideas.

And, as I forgot about the credentials part: Use ssh keys and an ssh-agent. This way, you only have to unlock your private key once and then use your unlocked private key to as many connections as you like.

Comment: ha, that looks exactly like what i want. awesome!

Comment: If you are using an up to date version of `ssh`, you don't need `netcat`. You can use `-W` instead. For example `ProxyCommand ssh -a -W %h:%p username@example.net`. I would not use `-X` inside the proxy command. And using %p seems like a better idea than hard-coding the port number. Using `-a` sort of makes sense, but it should be the default anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at PAC-SSH Manager http://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/

Comment: Yes, so far this is the only candidate I found.

Comment: This is the part that makes me sad : "It provides a GUI to configure connections". I'd love to have that integrated directly within my usual terminal and not rely on an external soft for that. Linux's CL is awesome, why not use it :S

Answer (score 0):

Can't you authorize using public/private key pairs?

Much more secure than storing the password somewhere on the hard disk. And you have the benefit that you do not need to enter the password when you jump from one host to another (or copy files using scp).

You generate a public/private key pair using ssh-keygen. Then you copy the public part to a ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on every host you want to login.

Using an ssh-agent on your local desktop you enter the passphrase only once after login and then you are able to login to every system without entering any password.

Comment: He's asking for a tool which is similar to moba on Linux, not the way he can connect to servers.

Comment: Yes, but he is also taking about the need to enter the credentials.